# Why phone adapters don't get very hot

Tags: amperage

I often hear that various electric heaters are able to reach high temperatures because of an exceptional resistivity of materials used to build their conductive circuits. It's kind of weird because this would imply a dramatic drop of amperage in the circuit, when in fact it drops less than it does when using a simple phone charger (which is supposedly less resistive than let's say nichrome heater winding), which brings the current down to around 200 miliamps while barely exceeding room temperature.

What am I missing?

Comment: Modern chargers are [switch mode power supplies (SMPS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply).  Usually, small chargers are a flyback topology.  To get an idea why switch mode power converters are relatively small, start with a simple SMPS like a [buck converter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buck_converter) works.  I must add that there is no "royal road" to switch mode power converters (i.e. you'll have to gnaw through some granite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that current is a function of both voltage and resistance.

The entire function of an electric heater is to convert electric current flow into heat energy. This is accomplished by passing current through a high resistance winding that is built to handle very high temperatures.

A phone charger, on the other hand, is intentionally built to avoid creating that heat, as it would be an unnecessary side effect, and it would waste power. Modern phone chargers use transistors to switch current flow through a coil on and off just the right way to maintain the correct voltage at its output. This way, you don't have to waste power in the form of heat to reduce the voltage to its target level.

So the biggest difference between the two is that the heater is designed to dissipate a certain amount of energy, whereas the charger is designed to *deliver* it.

Wikipedia has a reasonable article on [switched mode power supplies.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply) If you're interested, that will get you started on understanding more of how these kind of chargers work. If you just want rough generalizations, I'm sure the community here would answer more questions.

EDIT: I forgot to point out that the heat caused by the power delivered to a phone would be distributed along all of the components in the charging path, and ideally most of the heat generated would occur in the battery storing the charge. Ever felt your phone get hot? Yeah, that.

Answer (score 0):

A nichrome wire wire stripper like [this](http://www.coasteltools.com/prod_ct100.htm) is a tiny little wire, and consumes 3 watts.

A phone charger like [this](http://www.cultofmac.com/168407/why-apples-iphone-charger-is-a-high-tech-work-of-art/) is about a cubic inch, consumes maybe 5-10W.

The surface area of the phone charger is much greater than that of the wire, so the charger feels cooler. Also, the charger is not *trying* to be a heater, and is designed such that the majority of the power losses are in the battery itself, which is an even *bigger* radiator.